# How to display SPUser with presence indicator and contact card in custom webpart

Tags: web-part, spuser, presence-indication

I am trying to find a way to display two columns from a list item, values in the both the columns are of type `SPFieldUser`. Looking for a way to display their contact card just like the way it is displayed in `DispForm.aspx`.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will answer your question as you don't give a lot of detail of what you're trying to do, a custom solution, what language?

So, here's how to do it if you wrote a custom javascript web part, the HTML for the presence indicator would be the following:

(Replace *currentsite* and *userId* and *userName* with the appropriate values)

```
<span class="ms-noWrap">
   <span class="ms-spimn-presenceLink">
     <span class="ms-spimn-presenceWrapper ms-imnImg ms-spimn-imgSize-10x10">
       <img class="ms-spimn-img ms-spimn-presence-disconnected-10x10x32" 
    src="*currentsite*/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png?rev=23"  alt="" />
     </span>
   </span>
   <span class="ms-noWrap ms-imnSpan">
     <span class="ms-spimn-presenceLink">
       <img class="ms-hide" src="*currentsite*/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23"  alt="" />
     </span>
     <a class="ms-subtleLink" onclick="GoToLinkOrDialogNewWindow(this);return false;" href="*currentsite*/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=*userId*">*userName*</a>
   </span>
</span>
```

Comment: I am working on doing a custom webpart(visual) in C#, so server side code is fine with me. HTML tip as you mentioned could get me started.